# Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm sorry if this will sound like a dumb question but I just can't figure it out by myself. I tried searching the web but it seems that this error can be a result by quite a number of quite a number of causes. Anyway, here it goes:

I don't understand why I get this error in Xcode when I run my program...

Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

It further says:

`duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_iMonggoFetcherTableViewController._productsArray in /Users/iripple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CoreDataTrial-ecpjzknoorcqzcc‌​khlajnpwveols/Build/Intermediates/CoreDataTrial.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CoreD‌​ataTrial.build/Objects-normal/i386/iMonggoProductsTableViewController.o and /Users/iripple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CoreDataTrial-ecpjzknoorcqzcc‌​khlajnpwveols/Build/Intermediates/CoreDataTrial.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CoreD‌​ataTrial.build/Objects-normal/i386/iMonggoFetcherTableViewController.o for architecture i386`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There might be many reasons..**

one i experienced recently is i you duplicate constant definitions of variable in different classes.

Check the line after the crash..it will tell you more about the error.

Comment: it says duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_iMonggoFetcherTableViewController._productsArray in /Users/iripple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CoreDataTrial-ecpjzknoorcqzcckhlajnpwveols/Build/Intermediates/CoreDataTrial.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CoreDataTrial.build/Objects-normal/i386/iMonggoProductsTableViewController.o and /Users/iripple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CoreDataTrial-ecpjzknoorcqzcckhlajnpwveols/Build/Intermediates/CoreDataTrial.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CoreDataTrial.build/Objects-normal/i386/iMonggoFetcherTableViewController.o for architecture i386

Comment: as seen from your error you have productsArray in two classes.. and it is a constant.. so you will have to change its name on one of the class.. or you have to declare on as a property in the other class.